# In CodeIgniter, where should I declare my global variables?

Tags: codeigniter, global

I want to declare some global variables and global constants.  Normally, I would put them in the includes/global.php of my own custom framework.

Where should I define globals in CodeIgniter?  Here's an example of the globals I want to declare:

```
define('USERSTAT_OFFLINE', 0);
define('USERSTAT_ONLINE', 1);
define('USERSTAT_AWAY', 2);
define('USERSTAT_BUSY', 3);

$PAYMENT_PLANS = array();
$PAYMENT_PLANS[] = array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Trial');
$PAYMENT_PLANS[] = array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'Premium Plan');
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may utilise config file (**system/application/config/config.php**) to set configuration related variables.

Or use constant file (**system/application/config/constants.php**) to store site preference constants.

Comment: constants.php is good for the constants, but i don't think config.php is appropriate for global variables, because config.php, by it's name is for configuration settings, not for global variables.

Comment: It can be seen as site-wide configuration. Just autoload a config file containing your information and it's as good as global.