# How to describe global messages like notification,errors in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to describe global messages like defined as under,but i have no idea where to define it and how to use it,If some one can help me..

```
<?php
    $messages=array(
            'JAVASCRIPT_DISABLED'=>'Please enable JavaScript in your browser or upgrade to a JavaScript-enable browser to use '.$site_name,
    );

$common_messages=array(
    'REQ'=>'requied',
    'EXISTS'=>' already exists',
    'ADDED'=>' added successfully',
    'MODIFIED'=>' modified successfully',
    'SIZE_EXCEED'=>'Invalid file format or size',

);


//ADMIN PANEL MESSAGE...
$validation_messages=array(
        'INVALID_EMAIL'=>'Valid email '.$common_messages['REQ'],
        'INVALID_PASSWORD'=>'Valid password '.$common_messages['REQ'],
        'INVALID_LOGIN'=>'Invalid login detail',
        'ACCOUNT_DISABLED'=>'Account disabled or Deleted by admin',
        'SIZE_EXCEED'=>'Invalid file format or size',
        'FILE_CANNOT_EMPTY'=>'File cannot be empty'
);

//NOTIFICATION FLAGS
$notify=array(
    'error'=>'m=e',
    'added'=>'m=a',
    'modified'=>'m=m'
);
```

?>

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671813/in-code-igniter-where-should-i-declare-my-global-variables

Comment: it was about global constants i want to add custom messages like validation message or notification like that

Comment: Look for *flasher*, it's in the *session*. Please google first.

Comment: @m4t1t0 and yeah its not working for array...can u plz explain me how to use it in controller.as i am new to codeigniter and php.

Comment: @hakre .i have already googeled..but i am in confusion they are passing data like
$this->session->set_flashdata('foo', 'your request was saved...');
I want this value passed value from array describe some where,so my question is where to describe it nad how to use it in flashdata method?

Comment: You fill flashdata in that what is called "controller" in codeigniter. That is just a PHP function that gets executed. If the global variables thing didn't help you I can't help you either. Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create file in config folder e.g messageerror.php

add code to it

```
$config['errormessage'] = your message here;
```

and if you want to call it.

```
$this->load->config('messageerror');
```

use this `$this->config->item('errormessage')`

Answer (score 3):

why not using `config/constants.php` ?

you can simply add constants like:

```
    define('ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL','Please provide a valid email address'); 
    define('NOTIFY_LOGGED_IN','You are now logged in'); 
   //... and so on
```